# Using AJAX to redirect to another page with a message

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I have a list of 4 different `<li>` elements (everyone has a different unique id). When I click on then I want the page to redirect somewhere else and with `AJAX` send the unique id of the clicked `<li>`.

### process stages:

- Click on 1 out of 4 of the `<li>`s.
- Redirect from the main screen to `~/report/create` with a the `<li>`'s id.
- **For later** - the new page (`~/report/create/theUniqueId`) will load a popup with the same id (using GET method).

I have turned to read about AJAX. I didn't fully understand it *(I am new to this and that may be the reason for the question)*. I skimmed through some websites and came up with two solutions for it.

### Code #1:

```
function Handle_Window_Transfer(id){
    //window.location.href = "report/index";
    
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "https://localhost:44392/Report/Index",
        data: {id:id.toString()},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            if (data.redirect) {
                // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
                window.location.replace(data.redirect);
            } else {
                // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
                $("#my-form").replaceWith(data.form);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

### Code #2:

```
function Handle_Window_Transfer(id){
    let token = '@csrf';
    token = token.substr(42, 40);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: `https://localhost:44392/Report/Index`,
        data: { "id": id.toString() },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, textStatus) {
            if (data.redirect) {
                // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
                window.location.replace(data.redirect);
            } else {
                // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
                $("#my-form").replaceWith(data.form);
            }
        },
        error: function (err) {
            console.log($($(err.responseText)[1]).text())
            debugger;
        }
    });
}
```

I know that there might be some errors, (I mostly code and do the backend in ASP NET C# controllers and not in JS). And because of that I got the error:

### Error:

```
POST https://localhost:44392/Report/Index 405
```

I have searched the web and found some solutions which I didn't see how can I use them In my code.

If someone knows what is wrong with my code and how to solve it, I'll be very glad to hear that.

**Edit:**

### Error log:

*With Nlog filter I get:*

```
 `2022-12-10 00:26:18.4139|WARN|SvivaTeamVersion3.Controllers.ErrorController|405 
Error Occured. Path: /Report/Indexand QueryString`
```

*Without the Nlog filter:*
(every 405 error)

```
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6155|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware|Request matched endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector|Performing unprotect operation to key {3cc4e018-6684-43ab-8e65-dd40b306bd7e} with purposes ('C:\Users\User\source\repos\‏‏SvivaTeamVersion3 - עותק\SvivaTeamVersion3', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'Identity.Application', 'v2').
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler|AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware|Executing endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware|Executed endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware|POST requests are not supported
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/Error/405'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|Endpoint 'SvivaTeamVersion3.Controllers.ErrorController.HttpStatusCodeHandler (SvivaTeamVersion3)' with route pattern 'Error/{statusCode}' is valid for the request path '/Error/405'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware|Request matched endpoint 'SvivaTeamVersion3.Controllers.ErrorController.HttpStatusCodeHandler (SvivaTeamVersion3)'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationHandler|AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was successfully authenticated.
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware|Executing endpoint 'SvivaTeamVersion3.Controllers.ErrorController.HttpStatusCodeHandler (SvivaTeamVersion3)'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:44392/Report/Index application/x-www-form-urlencoded;+charset=UTF-8 7
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware|All hosts are allowed.
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware|POST requests are not supported
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/Report/Index'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware|Request matched endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector|Performing unprotect operation to key {3cc4e018-6684-43ab-8e65-dd40b306bd7e} with purposes ('C:\Users\User\source\repos\‏‏SvivaTeamVersion3 - עותק\SvivaTeamVersion3', 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationMiddleware', 'Identity.Application', 'v2').
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request starting HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:44392/Report/Index application/x-www-form-urlencoded;+charset=UTF-8 7
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.HostFiltering.HostFilteringMiddleware|All hosts are allowed.
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware|POST requests are not supported
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/Report/Index'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6204|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware|Request matched endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'

2022-12-10 00:28:49.6350|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware|Executing endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6350|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware|Executed endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6350|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware|Executing endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6350|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware|Executed endpoint '405 HTTP Method Not Supported'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6350|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware|POST requests are not supported
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6350|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware|POST requests are not supported
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6350|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/Error/405'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6350|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|Endpoint 'SvivaTeamVersion3.Controllers.ErrorController.HttpStatusCodeHandler (SvivaTeamVersion3)' with route pattern 'Error/{statusCode}' is valid for the request path '/Error/405'
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6350|DEBUG|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher|1 candidate(s) found for the request path '/Error/405'

2022-12-10 00:28:49.6517|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|Executing action method SvivaTeamVersion3.Controllers.ErrorController.HttpStatusCodeHandler (SvivaTeamVersion3) with arguments (405)
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6517|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|Executing action method SvivaTeamVersion3.Controllers.ErrorController.HttpStatusCodeHandler (SvivaTeamVersion3) with arguments (405)
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6517|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|Executing action method SvivaTeamVersion3.Controllers.ErrorController.HttpStatusCodeHandler (SvivaTeamVersion3) - Validation state: Valid
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6517|TRACE|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker|Executing action method SvivaTeamVersion3.Controllers.ErrorController.HttpStatusCodeHandler (SvivaTeamVersion3) with arguments (405)

2022-12-10 00:28:49.6830|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request     finished HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:44392/Report/Index     application/x-www-form-urlencoded;+charset=UTF-8 7 - 405 -     text/html;+charset=utf-8 74.3237ms
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6830|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request finished HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:44392/Report/Index application/x-www-form-urlencoded;+charset=UTF-8 7 - 405 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 62.4996ms
2022-12-10 00:28:49.6830|INFO|Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics|Request finished HTTP/2 POST https://localhost:44392/Report/Index application/x-www-form-urlencoded;+charset=UTF-8 7 - 405 - text/html;+charset=utf-8 60.3459ms
```

Without:

Comment: The error comes from the controller, 405 means `Method not allowed`. Can you share the error log from your backend?

Comment: It's a long file. Do you want me to add anything wherever it says anything about a 405 error? @FelixSchildmann

Comment: Okay, can you share the code of your controller endpoint for `'/Report/Index` as well please?

Answer (score 0):

Please try like this.

```
if (data.redirect) {
            // data.redirect contains the string URL to redirect to
            window.location.href = data.redirect + "/" + theUniqueId;
        } else {
            // data.form contains the HTML for the replacement form
            $("#myform").replaceWith(data.form);
        }
```

Comment: returns an error: `"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 ()"` - In the first function

Comment: second function returns this error: `"POST https://localhost:44392/Report/Index 405"` @DavidF

Comment: In the data there should be a redirection somehow maybe?

Comment: You don't even have data in the response because the request was unsuccessful (Error 405)

Comment: Yes. So the question still is how do I make it successful?

Comment: The data is just a string. And if I understand correctly the `if` statement checks if my data has some type of redirection. @FelixSchildmann

Comment: It doesnt even end up in the `success` part of the ajax so there's no data to check

Comment: It's probably a backend issue

Comment: Maybe it is the id.toString() is the cause? (I get the ID from a SQL server).
Would it be helpful if I add the Controller? @FelixSchildmann
BTW, I am moving this discussion to a chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250313/discussion-between-david-and-felix-schildmann).